# Garage fluorescent converted to LED suddenly "OFF" is on and on is "OFF"

Tags: led, light, fixtures

I switched a 2 lamp fluorescent fixture in my garage to LED early this year with no issues.
It worked flawlessly for the past 10 months.  Then, just today, when I switched the light "ON", nothing happened.  Then, when I switched it "OFF" the light came on. Now, for whatever reason, "OFF" is "ON" and vice-versa.  I have done no work to this fixture nor have I done any other electrical work that would have impacted this light.  Is my switch simply broken or is there a more serious issue?

Comment: Is there another switch somewhere that also turns this light on and off?

Comment: Imagine this is a simple single switch and not a three way(two switches for one light).  Funny this is the second in a month about a switch switching.  Replace with a new(better quality) switch.

Comment: no, only one light on this switch, not a 3-way.  I will start with a new switch

Comment: Usually, barring pranksters, this means someone flipped the other switch on the 3-way that you think does nothing becasue you don't know this switch is a 3-way. Take pictures **before** you disconnect any wires.

Comment: Take pics of the wiring and [edit] them into your question. Someone here will be able to tell you if this is a 3-way switch or not.